# Riverpod: Can I use the same Provider instance both inside and outside of the Widget tree?

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I want (sort of need) to use the same `Provider` instance both inside and outside of the widget tree. My understanding is that `ProviderContainer` is there so that you can create multiple, clean instances of a `Provider` while running tests. Can I use things like `context.read(myProvider)` and `myProviderContainer.read(myProvider)` on the same Provider instance?

Whether that approach works or not, if it's possible to do this, what is the best practice way?

Comment: No.  They would have different RootContainer instances, which is where the data (and metadata) actually lives.  Edit:  Oops, you intended them to be different, and if so, yes. :)

Comment: You had it right. I want/need them to be the exact same instance. Thank you for the explanation.